# Styling HTML form controls

Tags: html, css

How do I style 'reset', 'button' and 'file' input types, let's say with images?

Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately you file button can't be styled without applying [a hack](http://www.shauninman.com/archive/2007/09/10/styling_file_inputs_with_css_and_the_dom), but the other types can be styled like this:

```
<style type="text/css">
  input[type=button] {
    background-image: url(http://static3.grsites.com/archive/textures/blue/blue003.jpg);
    color: yellow;
    font-weight: bold;
  }

  input[type=reset] {
    background-image: url(http://static2.grsites.com/archive/textures/red/red003.jpg);
    color: yellow;
    font-weight: bold;
  }
</style>
```

Answer (score 0):

styled.css:

```
input[@type='button']
{
    background-image: url(button.png);
}

input[@type='reset']
{
    background-image: url(reset.png);
}

input[@type='file']
{
    background-image: url(file.png);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

HTML

```
<input type="button" name="buttonname" class="form-button" />
```

CSS

```
<style type="text/css">

.form-button
{
  background-image: url(image.gif);
}

</style>
```

Comment: I did something like this, it didn't work:
http://eximi.dreamhosters.com/Hawaii/html/contact_email.php

Here is my CSS:
input.print {
 background-image: url(../assets/images/print_btt.png);
 width: 119px;
 height: 47px;
}

input.upload {
 background-image: url(../assets/images/uf_btt.png);
 width: 119px;
 height: 47px;
}

 
input.reset {
 background-image: url(../assets/images/reset_btt.png);
 width: 119px;
 height: 47px;
}

Comment: HTML:
<input type="image" name="submit" id = "button" img src = "../assets/images/submit_btt.png" alt = "submit" />
     <input class="upload" type="file" name="uploadedfile" />
     <input class="reset" type="reset" />
     <input class="print" type="button" onclick="window.print()" />

Sorry, I'm new here and don't know how to add formatting to the code examples.